# Section after Header is aligned with Header?

Tags: html, css

Creating a mockup quick for a WP theme I'm working on a single page for, and I'm not certain what's occurring here. I've seen suggestions when using `absolute` or `fixed` positions to set a `margin-top` equal to the header, but the header is moving WITH the section styling as if its inheriting somewhere.

Inspecting and not seeing the cause. JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/je53s6hk/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `<div class="clearfix"></div>` this after end of header tag.

You have used float on header, so you need to clear the float for next elements.

and in your css
`.clearfix{clear: both;}`